# ****** Modify/Update LDAP Manager Attribute with Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm having an issue with modifying MANAGER attribute in Active Directory. I know that manager property is type of DN (distinguishedName). I have no problem updating any other properties like title, department, company(it's type of String), but how do i update DN manager property? Thanx All...

```
Dim de As DirectoryEntry
            If de.Properties.Contains("manager") Then
                de.Properties("manager")(0) = "Jack Smith"
            Else
                de.Properties("manager").Add("Jack Smith")
            End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to enter a full DN for Jack Smith, not just a string of his name.

So first you would have to find the DN of Jack Smith and then add it.

Comment: I've already found my answer, before i saw yours. You are CORRECT, you need to find this Manager(person) EXACT dn property and then set it.

Thanx a Lot.